# Force Subdomain to secure.domain.com rather than domain.com/secure

Tags: .htaccess

I have an SSL cert on a subdomain we have (secure), however if someone attempts to access the folder using this method:

`http://www.domain.com/secure`
or `https://www.domain.com/secure`

It shows the SSL error "ssl_error_bad_cert_domain" which is correct, so what I wanted to do was prevent anyone accessing the secure folder directly, instead forcing them to:

`https://secure.domain.com`

Which then ensures the SSL cert works correctly.

I am assuming this can be done using the .htaccess file in the subdomain folder (which already forces it to use https), but I'm just not sure how to accomplish it.

Many thanks.

**Update 1**
Including current subdomains .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Don't want to answer as I dont really know enough about htaccess but found this on a Google hope it helps. http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=141756

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to redirect from `https://www.domain.com/secure/`, because it will attempt to validate the certificate before it attempts any redirect.  You'd need a valid certificate covering "www.domain.com" for that to work.

To cover `http://www.domain.com/secure`, you can use the following.

```
Redirect 301 /secure/ https://secure.domain.com/
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, Have edited the domains, did miss the s of the http. https://secure.domain.com has the cert on.

Comment: I've updated the answer to match the updated question.  Let me know if you encounter any further troubles.